# How to keep the screen on in Universal phone app?

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app

Before Windows Universal, if I wanted to prevent the screen from turning off, I could use:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

That API is now gone and I can't find anything like it.  Can someone help me find the right way to do this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at DisplayRequest class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2. It's intended to apps which

> show video or run for extended periods without user input

so it should be a solution.

Comment: That's perfect.  The DisplayRequest.RequestActive() and RequestRelease() methods are the way to go.  Thanks!